# Display popups with content specific to the clicked container

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

I've 6 div and I need that when I click in one div, appear a popup in this div, and if I click another div appear a popup in this other div. I know how to do that in one div, with getElementById, but I don't know how do that in some different div. This is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="novels__gallery popup" onclick="popupFunction()">
  <img class="novels__gallery-img" src="images/fantasia.jpg" alt="Camí fantàstic" title="Camí fantàstic">
  <div class="novels__gallery-title">Fantasia</div>
  <span class="popupText" id="myPopup">Coming Soon!</span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function popupFunction() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

This works for one div, but don't for another div. I supose that getElementsByClassName works but I don't know how to apply correctly it.

Thanks!!

Comment: Use `querySelector`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript: How to get only one element by class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21436550/javascript-how-to-get-only-one-element-by-class-name)

Comment: @expressjs123 `querySelector` won't help this case because it only selects the first matched element.

Comment: @yqlim But here, the class names are all unique - so no need for matching any weir delements

Comment: @expressjs123 I believe the OP is only showing only 1 chunk of the page

Comment: @yqlim Oh...  then the OP can add an id to the element

Comment: If I use a querySelector, when I click on the second div, the popup appears on the first div, and if I click another div, the popup appears on the first div too

Comment: check my answer guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create one div that will operate as the pop-up, and populate its contents from the source div that was clicked.

I built the function step-by-step so you can easily follow the logic.

The modal is displayed by changing the css display property from `display:none` to `display:flex`. It is hidden by removing the class that contains the `display:flex`, turning it back to `display:none`.

Note that the code *looks a bit like* jQuery, but it is pure js.

```js
const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
const mdl = $('#modal');

function popupFunction(e) {
  const targ = e.target;
  const prnt = targ.closest('div.popup');
  const chldn = prnt.childNodes;
  const txt = [...chldn].filter((d) => d.className === 'popupText');
  const msg = txt[0].innerText;
  $('#modal .body').innerText = msg;
  $('#modal').classList.add('modalHasContent');
}
function closeModal(e){
  e.target.classList.remove('modalHasContent');
}
```

```css
#modal{
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
#modal .body{
  width: 400px;
  background: wheat;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  padding: 15px 25px;
}
.modalHasContent{
  display: flex !important;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
.popupText{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="novels__gallery popup" onclick="popupFunction(event)">
  <img class="novels__gallery-img" src="https://placekitten.com/250/100">
  <div class="novels__gallery-title">Fantasia</div>
  <span class="popupText">Coming Soon!</span>
</div>
<div class="novels__gallery popup" onclick="popupFunction(event)">
  <img class="novels__gallery-img" src="https://placekitten.com/240/90">
  <div class="novels__gallery-title">Despicable Me</div>
  <span class="popupText">That's what I'm talking about!</span>
</div>

<div id="modal" onclick="closeModal(event)">
  <div class="body"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a working snippet :

```js
const boxes= document.querySelectorAll('.box')
const popups= Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.popup'))

boxes.forEach((box,index)=>{
box.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
popupFunction(index)
})
})

function popupFunction(index) {
  popups[index].classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
.popup{
  display:none
}
.show{
  display:block
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  box1

</div>
<div class="box">
  box2

</div>
<div class="box">
  box3

</div>

<div class="popup" >
   <img src=""> 
  <span class="popupText">popup from box 1 </span> 
</div> 

<div class="popup" > 
   <img src="">
   <span class="popupText"> popup from box 2 </span> </div> 

<div class="popup" >
  <img src=""> 
  <span class="popupText"> popup from box 3 </span> 
</div>
```

Comment: I've tryed and don't works. I leave a simple example. We have 3 boxes, and onclick, appear a little popup with some text to clicked box.

<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="popup" onclick="popupFunction()">
    <img src="">
    <span class="popupText"> Coming Soon </span>
  </div>
  <div class="popup" onclick="popupFunction()">
    <img src="">
    <span class="popupText"> Coming Soon </span>
  </div>
  <div class="popup" onclick="popupFunction()">
    <img src="">
    <span class="popupText"> Coming Soon </span>
  </div>
</div>
</body>

Comment: here is a working example https://codepen.io/SAIDESIGNER/pen/JjKwrpW

Comment: Press Ctrl + M to make a working example inside your answer (called a Stack Snippet)

Comment: @cssyphus thank you I just find codepen quicker , ll create a snippet now here

Comment: @cssyphus check my snippet

Comment: This is a codepen with similar code. I need some javascript to do the same that your codepen. https://codepen.io/baes13/pen/mdEaqJa

Comment: @SaiduSenpay Yes, that looks great. We don't mind members using fiddles/codepens, but for simple solutions it is helpful to see the code nicely segmented and runnable inside your answer.

Comment: @alexbaes You are expanding the original question and basically requesting two answers for the price of one. Please choose a correct answer for this question and then open another question to expand on this one, and post a comment below this answer with a URL link to the new question so that Saidu can easily find it.

Comment: Sorry, is my first question on Stackoverflow and I don't know much about Javascript yet. If you prefer I delete this post, and I open a new question with mycodepen example directly. I only need to show a message for every image that someone click.

Comment: @alexbaes its okkay we all start somewhere , so if it worked please mark this a correct answer

Comment: @cssyphus I really didn't get the "answering two questions part " as far as I know this is a working solution for the question right ?

Comment: Yes, yours was a working solution. Upvoted. My comment was for Alex. When an answer DOES answer the question as originally written, but the questioner (the "OP") then requests a pretty big change to *fine-tune* the answer, that isn't really fair. The OP is really asking for a second answer even though the first answer was correct for what was originally asked. In these cases, we ask the OP to accept the best answer and ask a new question right away. It should only take an extra minute or two. But then the person who answered the first question is rewarded for their answer, AND

Comment: the second question will be viewed by dozens of new people who will all try to help. But if the OP *fine-tunes* the question, then only the person who answered the original question will see their change request and try to assist. This isn't really fair to the person who answered the first question, and it could take A LOT longer for the second question to be answered.  So asking a second question is much better for both the OP *and* the answerer.

Comment: @cssyphus ah yeah I get it I was confused hhh . sure asking new question is better fo the questioner and for the community too

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution but it is not what I need. I have the wrong question, excuse me.

Comment: New answer provided - but please see comments below Saidu's answer. These are not criticisms of anyone's actions, but rather suggestions on how to optimize the experience for all parties.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite: [My jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Intacto/f8whztq6/)

```js
function popupAct(t) {
    m=document.getElementById("modal");
    m.firstElementChild.innerHTML=t.firstElementChild.innerHTML;
  m.classList.add('modalHasContent');
}
```

```css
#modal{
  z-index: 9999;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#modal .body:before{
  float:right;
  display: block;
  content: "\00d7";
  padding:10px;
}
#modal .body{
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 10%;
  background-color: white;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: calc(100% - 30%);
}
.modalHasContent{
  display: flex !important;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
.popupText{display: none;}
```

```html
<div id="modal" onclick="this.classList.remove('modalHasContent')"><div class="body"></div></div>

<div align="justify"><span>Dr. Brrerere Krrerererer, MD, MPH<br>
<br>
Dr. werwerwerwererwerw wer wer wer wer wer wer tr tyj tyj tyj tyj hrth rth rth rth rt ty juyk yuk yuk yyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyjtyj tyjtyj tyj tyj tyjtyjty jtyj tyj tyj tyj tyj y University (MPH).</span>

<div onclick="popupAct(this);" style="float: right; cursor: pointer; padding: 10px; text-align: justify;">Read more 

<span class="popupText"><b>Dr. B sdf sdf sdf werwerwerwererwerw <br><br> Eer wer wer wer wer wer tr tyj tyj tyj tyj hrth rth rth rth rt ty juyk yuk yuk yyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyjtyj tyjtyj tyj tyj tyjtyjty jtyj tyj tyj tyj tyj y D, MPH</b>
<br><br>
werwerwerwererwerw wer wer wer wer wer wer tr tyj tyj tyj tyj hrth rth rth rth rt ty juyk yuk yuk yyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyjtyj tyjtyj tyj tyj tyjtyjty jtyj tyj tyj tyj tyj y werwerwerwererwerw wer wer wer wer wer wer tr tyj tyj tyj tyj hrth rth rth rth rt ty juyk yuk yuk yyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyjtyj tyjtyj tyj tyj tyjtyjty jtyj tyj tyj tyj tyj y.
<br><br>
werwerwerwererwerw wer wer wer wer wer wer tr tyj tyj tyj tyj hrth rth rth rth rt ty juyk yuk yuk yyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyjtyj tyjtyj tyj tyj tyjtyjty jtyj tyj tyj tyj tyj y werwerwerwererwerw wer wer wer wer wer wer tr tyj tyj tyj tyj hrth rth rth rth rt ty juyk yuk yuk yyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyjtyj tyjtyj tyj tyj tyjtyjty jtyj tyj tyj tyj tyj y werwerwerwererwerw wer wer wer wer wer wer tr tyj tyj tyj tyj hrth rth rth rth rt ty juyk yuk yuk yyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyjtyj tyjtyj tyj tyj tyjtyjty jtyj tyj tyj tyj tyj y werwerwerwererwerw wer wer wer wer wer wer tr tyj tyj tyj tyj hrth rth rth rth rt ty juyk yuk yuk yyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyjtyj tyjtyj tyj tyj tyjtyjty jtyj tyj tyj tyj tyj y.
<br><br>
werwerwerwererwerw wer wer wer wer wer wer tr tyj tyj tyj tyj hrth rth rth rth rt ty juyk yuk yuk yyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyjtyj tyjtyj tyj tyj tyjtyjty jtyj tyj tyj tyj tyj y werwerwerwererwerw wer wer wer wer wer wer tr tyj tyj tyj tyj hrth rth rth rth rt ty juyk yuk yuk yyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyjtyj tyjtyj tyj tyj tyjtyjty jtyj tyj tyj tyj tyj y werwerwerwererwerw wer wer wer wer wer wer tr tyj tyj tyj tyj hrth rth rth rth rt ty juyk yuk yuk yyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyjtyj tyjtyj tyj tyj tyjtyjty jtyj tyj tyj tyj tyj y werwerwerwererwerw wer wer wer wer wer wer tr tyj tyj tyj tyj hrth rth rth rth rt ty juyk yuk yuk yyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyjtyj tyjtyj tyj tyj tyjtyjty jtyj tyj tyj tyj tyj y<br><br><br><br><br>wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww 
 werwerwerwererwerw wer wer wer wer wer wer tr tyj tyj tyj tyj hrth rth rth rth rt ty juyk yuk yuk yyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyjtyj tyjtyj tyj tyj tyjtyjty jtyj tyj tyj tyj tyj y werwerwerwererwerw wer wer wer wer wer wer tr tyj tyj tyj tyj hrth rth rth rth rt ty juyk yuk yuk yyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyjtyj tyjtyj tyj tyj tyjtyjty jtyj tyj tyj tyj tyj y werwerwerwererwerw wer wer wer wer wer wer tr tyj tyj tyj tyj hrth rth rth rth rt ty juyk yuk yuk yyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyj tyjtyj tyjtyj tyj tyj tyjtyjty jtyj tyj tyj tyj tyj y 
 </span>
 </div>
```